# IText Constructor not Throwing Exception or Following Flow

Tags: java, exception, pdf, itext

I have a static method used to get the title from a PDF using the metadata via itext, which is used as a small part of a major Task.

I noticed an inexplicable path that I narrowed down to this section of code. Specifically, in the line where I instantiate a PdfReader, the process doesn't throw an exception or continue through to the print statement. In fact, it clears out all of my for loops up to the top level of my program and acts as if nothing has happened and my task completed.

```
try {
    System.out.println("Entered method");
    PdfReader myReader = new PdfReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Reader instantiated"); //if no issues, prints to console
    Map<String, String> info = myReader.getInfo();
    System.out.println(info.get("Title"));
    return info.get("Title");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("PdfReader throws exception"); //if issues, prints to console
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Unless I'm mistaken, when this set of code is executed in my method, either "Reader Instantiated" or "PdfReader throws exception" is printed out to the console.

Neither happens. Instead, the process skips every if/for/while loop it is currently in and ends the task.

I'm wondering if someone can explain to me what is happening and how I should go about fixing it?

Comment: Try catching `Throwable` instead of `IOException`. Does something different happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the odd event this is searched for, yes, catching `Throwable` stops the thread from bailing out. I had never seen something like this before. The cause behind the problem was that a PDF was password-protected, so `getInfo()` failed.

Comment: For encryption and decryption iText makes use of external libraries which you probably don't have on your class path. In That case some Error is thrown which bypasses your catch clause.

Comment: @mkl as far as I remember, the only issue was that it bypassed it. Another method I had which actually opened the PDF in iText would properly throw an Exception for password protected. This one threw a Throwable instead, and no error, Exception, or stack trace ever came up, which made it a nightmare to debug.

Comment: A Throwable generally is either an Exception or an Error. As you catch all declared exceptions, only Errors and RuntimeExceptions remain. In your case most likely a class-not-found thing.